# trying to install ROS from source on UBUNTU 13.10

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to install ROS from source on UBUNTU 13.10, and gets stock on the `qt_qui_cpp` package and gives this error:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'qt_gui_cpp'
==> Building with env: '/home/ltorabi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/ltorabi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
==> make -j2 -l2 in '/home/ltorabi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
[ 76%] Built target qt_gui_cpp
[ 84%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
sip: Deprecation warning: qt_gui_cpp.sip:1: %Module version number should be specified using the 'version' argument
sip: Unable to find file "QtCore/QtCoremod.sip"
Error: Unable to open
"/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/pyqtscripting.sbf"
make[2]: *** [sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'qt_gui_cpp':
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98016/trying-to-install-ros-from-source-on-ubuntu-13.10/) by [ltorabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8461/ltorabi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like your `qt` libraries either aren't installed or aren't up-to-date. I would try doing that and then attempting installation again.

---

Originally posted by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) with karma: 320 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ltorabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8461/ltorabi/) on 2013-11-05**:
Thanks for the quick answer, but I got the updated qt_gui_cpp from the repository :
Source: git https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core (branch: groovy-devel) and still doesn't work

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-05**:
Check your system dependencies not your ROS dependencies.

**Comment by [ltorabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8461/ltorabi/) on 2013-11-06**:
Thanks a lot. I got passed that by installing PYQT4, but then gives me the following error even though I used  configure.py and not  configure-ng.py for installing Pyqt4:

[ 84%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...

File "/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 3, in

```
from PyQt4 import pyqtconfig
```

ImportError: cannot import name pyqtconfig

So I am not sure what is the "pyqtconfig" !! Is it a module or a .py file, and where should be located. Because as I see the pyqtconfig.py is configured and located in the  "PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3" folder not in the "/usr/share/sip/PyQt4" folder

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error may also happen if you are trying to build ROS with jade inUubuntu 15.10 (or other version of ROS or ubuntu).

It is solved if you install a few packages:

> $ sudo apt-get install sip-dev python-qt4-dev python-sip-dev pyqt4-dev-tools

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paol](https://answers.ros.org/users/32234/paol/) on 2017-10-18**:
This fixed it for us in Ubuntu 17.04, but nowadays the packages to install are a little different:

```
sudo apt-get install sip-dev pyqt5-dev python-sip-dev pyqt5-dev-tools
```